# HDMI KVM switch not recognizing laptop

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, kvm-switch

I need to use my single monitor (HDMI, Samsung SyncMaster B2430) and keyboard / mouse (USB, Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic) with 2 laptops, to be able to switch between the two easily with one click of a button.

My 1st laptop is my old Samsung Series 9 NP900X4C, running Windows 10 Home (with a micro HDMI port).

My 2nd laptop is a Dell Precision 5520, running Windows 10 Enterprise (with full HDMI port)

Up till a few months ago I was using a cheap HDMI Switch, (3-port Duronic).

It was working fine (I was switching the keyboard separately by swapping the dongle), but at some point it stopped recognising my Samsung Laptop. I thought it was something wrong with the HDMI switch, given its such a cheap device, and didn't bother doing any more troubleshooting.

Instead I went ahead and bought a Bowu 2 USB HDMI KVM-Switch. This one also takes USB so with one button I also switch the keyboard and mouse, not just the monitor.
The USB switching works perfectly between the two laptops on the new KVM switch.

The problem is that when I connect my Samsung laptop through the new switch the monitor does not recognize the signal. But when I connect them directly it works, so I know that the HDMI port on my laptop is not busted. It is also strange that both HDMI switches are behaving in this way.

```
Samsung Laptop -> Monitor = OK

Samsung Laptop -> KVM Port 1 -> Monitor = NOK
Dell Laptop -> KVM Port 2 -> Monitor = OK

Dell Laptop -> KVM Port 1 -> Monitor = OK
Samsung Laptop -> KVM Port 2 -> Monitor = NOK
```

I also tried swapping cables to eliminate the possibility of a faulty cable.

Given that this used to work before with my old HDMI switch, and suddenly it stopped, I am starting to suspect it must be some driver or windows update issue that screwed this up, or some display setting which somehow is not compatible, although I don't recall changing any resolution or display settings.

Is there any way or any tool I could use to debug what is going on when the HDMI handshake takes place between my laptop and monitor through the KVM?

Comment: Try to power cycle the KVM On/Off several times.

Comment: @harrymc No luck. Tried also the old HDMI switch, same symptoms. The Dell laptop works fine on both. The Samsung laptop works fine direct, but not through the switcher. Powered off and on multiple times.

Comment: I wonder if the Samsung's video adapter is weakening, so cannot punch the signal through.

Comment: It's an Intel HD graphics 4000. I reinstalled the driver today, still no luck. Any way to test the signal hypotheses, or to measure it in some way? Would a shorter hdmi cable help?

Comment: HDMI is digital signal, so would need several meters for degrading it. An HDMI Cable Signal Tester  is not cheap. Trying a better cable wouldn't hurt, anyway, as one test. You might also have a look if the video driver for the Samsung was updated at about the time the problem started, and study its available settings.

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought, but out of ideas now. Tried a couple of cables. I tried to update the Intel display driver too, since it comes with a tool to customize options, no luck so far either :(

Comment: Last effort for software: Which video driver are you using for the Samsung? Try to delete the video adapter, close the computer using the power button and reboot.

Comment: @harrymc Still no luck. The driver was the one that comes with the laptop. I tried to delete the video adaptor, and rebooted. The old one (2015) appeared. Still same problem. Then I tried to do Update Driver, and chose another version updated in 2017. Then I tried to change to Microsoft Generic Adaptor but it screwed up the resolution, and the options to select Extend or Duplicate screen went away. Finally downloaded manually Intel's latest drivers (16/08/2018) and updated the driver manually (Have Disk... option etc) and things came back to normal, but still no dual screen through KVM :(

Comment: Another interesting observation, when I switch the KVM to the problematic laptop, under Monitors in Device Manager, a second "Generic PnP Monitor" appears. When I switch away from it to the other laptop it goes away. So something of some sort is going through.

Comment: Try pressing [windows key] + [P] on the problem laptop. Does selecting "Extend" (or duplicate) causes it to show up on the monitor? I'm wondering if it decides not to automatically display on the KVM monitor for some reason.

Comment: No. The screen remains black. I tried to change from duplicate to extend and back like a hundred times.

Comment: The "Generic PnP Monitor" means that the KVM is not passing through the EDID info of the monitor. I would suggest replacing it with one that does.

Comment: @harrymc But even when I connect my monitor directly, and it works, it still shows Generic PnP Monitor. Even the laptop's own screen shows as Generic PnP Monitor (so I get 2 when I connect the monitor, with or without the KVM). Can't see why the KVM should show something different if even direct it shows the same.

Comment: Then there is also another problem. Which monitor does that, or do all monitors?

Comment: I only have 1 monitor (Samsung SyncMaster B2430). Then there is the laptop's own screen. Both show Generic PnP Monitor in device manager. Both work fine (when not using the KVM in between).

Comment: @jbx, you should install fresh windows on Samsung laptop. It's the only way and can solve your problem 99 percents.

Comment: There is a download driver for the monitor [here](https://www.samsung.com/ca/support/model/LS24PUHKFV/ZA/), although it is for Windows 7 and might not work, but may still be worth trying. It seems like Windows 10 does not really support this monitor and the NP900X4C. Using a driver from non-manufacturer sources is strongly not recommended.

Comment: @harrymc Installed the driver. Now I get SyncMaster B2340H (Digital) whenever I plug the monitor in, although I selected which Generic PnP Monitor the driver should apply to myself when installing it, I doubt anything smart is going on. Connecting the monitor directly works perfectly (as before), through KVM it remains blank :(

Comment: @Tom hardly a reason to reinstall my PC! Especially if it turns out to be some hardware issue.

Comment: @jbx, finally you have to reinstall windows. you waste your time.

Comment: @Tom I want to understand what is going on. I can't reinstall windows for every petty issue. Its just an ignorant solution.

Comment: @harrymc Out of curiosity I checked my other Dell laptop (which also works through the KVM). And it also shows both screens (its own screen and the connected Samsung one) as `Generic PnP Monitor`. So I don't think that is really the issue.

Comment: I find it very curious that all the monitors come up as Generic. I also think it's worthwhile trying a better KVM.

Comment: @harrymc yeah, but the fact that 2 HDMI switches are behaving this way, doesn't encourage me much to buy another one, especially if the problem is not from there

Comment: Without more tests the only credible conjecture is that the old Samsung has a hardware problem that weakens its video signal, which I already raised above.

Comment: @harrymc I am starting to suspect that too. Just tried an experiment where I connected my wife's laptop (a very similar samsung series 9, just a bit smaller, and maybe a year less old)... and it worked fine through the KVM :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long exchange with the poster, and quite a few tests,
the relevant points that are left are listed below:

- The Samsung Series 9 no longer works through two different KVMs
- Two other computers have no problem getting through both KVMs
- The Samsung Series 9 can directly connect to the monitor, just not through any KVM.

My conclusion is a hardware degradation on the Samsung's video adapter.
Perhaps a weaker video signal has some problem punching through a KVM.

As the video adapter is integrated into the motherboard, it's likely not
worthwhile to further invest in this computer.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. In the end I solved the problem with a workaround, connected the good old VGA port (the laptop has a mini VGA port), directly to the VGA port of the monitor. So the KVM is unfortunately only serving for the keyboard, but with an extra push on the monitor I switch the source. Choosing your answer so that you get the bounty.